# I can't make an image transparent on Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I tried everything, but it didn't work. Please help me

[image: See Screenshot]

Comment: show your image `drawable/cart`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do it to download a transparent img of a cart and adjust the width and length you can  also download it with the link below 
https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/shopping-cart_833314?term=cart&page=1&position=3&page=1&position=3&related_id=833314&origin=search

Answer (score -1):

If you have taken this image from your storage then you can simply convert it's background transparent by using any background remover tool online such as this one:
[remove background](https://www.remove.bg/)

Comment: This is not answering the question. The OP request was to make a drawable transparent in code/xml - not removing background or changing the source file.